# Best Practices and Flavor for Running DaVinci Resolve

Tags: nvidia, performance, davinci-resolve

Short of learning a [new distro entirely](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=183848), but staying within the Ubuntu family, what are best practices and flavors for running a resource-hungry and somewhat update-finicky application like DaVinci Resolve?

Currently running MATE (22.04), and the primary application I wish to optimize for is DaVinci Resolve. Would there be big enough return on investment in terms of processing power freed up or similar, to justify taking the time and effort to reinstall and learning a new Ubuntu flavour, such as Ubuntu Studio or lightweight Lubuntu?

In the same note, my Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu updates will somewhat frequently (about 2-4 times a year), cause an issue with DaVinci that needs to be worked around by either purging the drivers, disabling secure boot or downgrading to a previous kernel, or something else I haven't learned about yet, I'm sure. Short of waiting a few weeks before installing new updates and making sure I am in between projects, are there other best practices I can implement to reduce the risk of downtime, but still making sure that my system stays up to date and secure?

Comment: PS: I hope I managed to ask this question within the "Constructive subjective" guidelines. Although I do hope, but am not sure if, there is a black and white answer.

Comment: I personally don't know anything about DaVinci Resolve, and what libraries/toolkits it uses; which will impact its requirements and thus choosing a desktop that will share these resources (*rather than DE & your wanted app using different resources thus leaving less RAM available for your app*). Outside of RAM used by the DE; all Ubuntu *flavors* use the same Ubuntu base, thus difference is minimal & just what *libs/toolkit* is used. MATE is GTK3, GNOME is GTK4, LXQt is Qt5 etc so *flavor* choice is mostly DE usage + what libraries it needs; sharing resources most efficient; updates identical

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining it so clearly! Will have to do some more digging/learning into the different libraries and how they work then.